# Image rendition button in the ribbon (EditForm.aspx) is greyed out?

Tags: image-rendition

I am using image renditions. I have created some custom image renditions sizes. I have enabled blob cache because it is needed for this functionality. When I add a new item to my list, one of the fields is an publish image. I can select an image and I can select the custom image rendition size.

[image]

Everything is working fine here. But sometimes I try to edit an existing saved item. I click on the image. After this you see an extra tab in the ribbon special for the selected image. I see here some button greyed out. Why is it greyed out?

It looks like you can can change the image rendition with this button.

[image]

Comment: Any luck solving the issue? Same problem here. Doesn't matter if I have the image in the current web or on site collection level. Image renditions work within the library, the renditions button on an `Image` field in another list is always disabled.

Comment: Found this little script from Waldek: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/using-image-renditions-with-images-from-other-site-collections/ but still doesn't help my case. Image Renditions still grayed out on a list item with an Image field, pointing to some images library.

Comment: Hi Dennis, no I didnt fixed it yet.

Comment: Doesn't work in both SP 2013 and Office365. Using jquery I tried to remove the grayed-out overlay of the button and hack it, but the dropdown with renditions doesn't appear. Seems like the "Pick Rendition" button is meant to be used in Publishing pages only.

Comment: Are the publishing features enabled in the site you are performing ?

Comment: Yes, publishing is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It think blob cache is not activated properly. Could you make sure if cache is being created in the blob folder that you mentioned in web.config? In any case, I would suggest configuring the blob cache again.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem related to blob cache. I can reproduce the issue consistently in Office 365 where blob cache should not be a concern. Here are reproduction steps: Create Custom List -> List Settings -> Add from existing site columns -> Add "Page Image" column -> create an item in the list and add image to the Page Image column -> in NewForm.aspx or EditForm.asox click on the image -> the "Pick Rendition" button in the ribbon is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have the appropriate permission or not. In Office 365 I am able to click on Edit Renditions from ribbon Please find attachement[image]. Also please check whether it is under trusted site or not.

[image]